Earning through surveys haram?
Assalamu alaykum
There is a website called surveys24, that pays me just for visiting some website, I click on certain links, takes to a website and they ask me to stay a while in that page so that the task in completed. There are some websites that are about haram thinhs, I don't visit them, I can see the title before surfing.
Now my question am I earning halal money or should I stop?

https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa-birmingham/171697/is-the-income-halal-received-for-filling-in-online-surveys/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_ayR5ua2gw
There's multiple results on Google if you look up the title of your question. Are they not sufficient?
